# How to verify password function in a Chatroom with nodejs and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to verify the password of a chat room, but it complicates me when the 2nd user enters. The first user is supposed to define what the password will be but when the 2nd user enters, I cannot retain the first password.

I have this on server side:

```
//Run when client connects
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
socket.on("joinRoom", ({ username, room, password }) => {
const user = userJoin(socket.id, username, room, password);
socket.join(room);
socket.join();
});
```

And in the client side:

```
//Join Chatroom
socket.emit("joinRoom", { username, room, password });
```

I have done this function but it doesn't work from what I was telling before:

Server side:

```
socket.on("checkPassword", ({ username, room, password}) => {
  const user = userJoin(socket.id, username, room);
       if (password1 == password) {
         io.sockets.emit("passwordFeedback", "correct");
       }else{
         io.sockets.emit("passwordFeedback", "wrong");
       }
})
```

`password1` it supposed to be the password inserted by the first user.
`password` it supposed to be the password inserted by the second user.
If I store the first password (which should be stored and then compared with the password entered by a second user), it fails, just store the current user connection.

Client side:

```
//Join private room
  socket.emit("checkPassword", { username, room, password });
  socket.on("passwordFeedback", function (flag) {
    if (flag == "correct") {
      console.log('password match')
    }else{
      console.log('password didnt match')
      alert("Incorrect Password!");
    }
  });
```

Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

Server:

```
let rooms = {}
io.of('/test').on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Connected', socket.id);

    socket.on("joinRoom", ({ username, room, password }) => {
        let isEntryAvailable = userJoin(socket.id, username, room, password);
        if (isEntryAvailable) {
            socket.emit('passwordFeedback', 'correct')
        } else {
            socket.emit('passwordFeedback', 'wrong')
        }
    })
    
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        io.of('/test').emit('message', 'user disconnected '+ socket.id);
        if (rooms[rooms[socket.id]] && Object.keys(rooms[rooms[socket.id]]).length == 2) {
            delete rooms[rooms[socket.id]];
        } else {
            if (rooms[rooms[socket.id]] && rooms[rooms[socket.id]][socket.id]) {
                delete rooms[rooms[socket.id]][socket.id];
            }
        }
        delete rooms[socket.id];
        console.log('Disonnected', socket.id);
        console.log(rooms);
    })

    function userJoin (socketId, username, room, password) {
        if (!rooms[room] || (rooms[room] && !rooms[room].password)) {
            if (!rooms[room]) {
                rooms[room] = {};
            }
            rooms[room].password = password;
            rooms[room][socketId] = username;
            rooms[socketId] = room;
            return true;
        } else {
            if (rooms[room].password == password) {
                rooms[socketId] = room;
                rooms[room][socketId] = username;
                socket.join(room);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Client:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000/test');

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected', socket.id);
    socket.emit('joinRoom', { room: 'room0', username: 'name1', password: 'pass@1234' });
})

socket.on('passwordFeedback', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: thanks, I follow your steps and it worked, nice logic